# Combining parts of original Android with newer sources to create a new image

Tags: compiling, android, source, binary

Hi I wanted to talk to the pros on the compiling and decompiling Android source and binaries respectively. Is it possible to decompile an Android OS running in a device and get its source, so that you can extract useful things such as device drivers that you can also use later to compile another binary (image) that can be installed on the same device but with the edited source.

For example I have a Samsung AAAA with android 2.3.3 and it's working fine and I want it to have android 4.0.4 ... can I decompile the image it has now (2.3.3) to source (2.3.3) then take the drivers or some other source element join it with a segment of the source of 4.0.4 to make a new image (binary with some drivers from 2.3.3 and some source from 4.0.4) then use this image flash it into the device Samsung AAAA.

Is it possible help much appreciated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Android, which is not a Unix-like operating system (despite being based on a Linux kernel). It may be on-topic on [android.se] or on [reverseengineering.se].

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no.

Yes, you can (usually) take older source code and combine it with newer one. That is what for example [CyanogenMod](http://www.cyanogenmod.org/) is doing (apart from other things).

No, you can't decompile the built image, extract sources, drop those verbatim into newer sources and recompile. It's just not that simple, for couple of reasons, mainly:

1. Decompilation is just not the inverse of compilation. The usual way code is processed is compiling the sources ad linking them into an executable (or a library; on a UNIX systems usually an [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) file these days). Decompilation can't (without additional data) reproduce the original source, instead you'll end up with assembly code, that uses identifiers present in the binary. Rougly in C speak: whatever is an exported object will be named correctly, but `static` things won't. Whatever gets inlined by the compiler (or linker if [LTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interprocedural_optimization) is employed when the image is built) will be just a blob of code unrecognisable from parts that were regular statements in a function.
2. API conmpatibility. Even with original source code for say a kernel device driver there is no guarantee that you can just use it without any changes  to compile it against in newer kernel. Internal kernel structures might change and especially earlier Android kernels were heavily patched (i.e. very different from the vanilla trees).

That said, it is not impossible. For the starter, check CM (CyanogenMod) and other alternate ROMs - you might not be the first one with exact the same problem. If that doesn't work and you are (or want to become) capable enough, you probably want to get the original kernel sources for your device (yes, they **must** be accessible somewhere, if they were not the company would be risking uncomfortable lawsuits) and use that and newer Android kernel as starting points. Also, the alternate ROMs communities or the [Android SE](https://android.stackexchange.com/) will be a better place to ask more specific questions than here.